# Average rotation from 10 3x3 rotation matrices

Tags: matrices, rotations, average

Let's say I have 10 3x3 rotation matrices. They were sampled and are all close to each other. I know there is a true rotation matrix which is a statistical aggregation of the 10 matrices (average rotation!). How would I be able to calculate the approximated correct matrix from the aggregation of the 10?

Comment: To be clear, by a rotation matrix, do you mean a $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ real orthogonal matrix with determinant $1$?

Comment: 3x3 real orthogonal matrix yes. With 2x2, I could just take the mean angle, right?! But I wanted even more than that. A 4x4 homogeneous matrix (with rotation and translation). That would be even nicer.

Comment: If you mean to find a $2\times2$ rotation matrix $R$ such that $R^{10}=R_{10}R_9\cdots R_1$, yes, you can take the mean angle. This gives not an approximation but the exact answer.

Comment: This is actually a good question with good answers from several viewpoints and  related to the classical orthogonal Procrustes problem. It should be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different answers depending on what you mean by "correct". One point of view is to think that the "true" rotation $R_{true}$ is perturbed by random changes with a known distribution, and $R_{measured}$ has a distribution that is dependent on $R_{true}$, $P(R_{measured}|R_{true})$. Once this is known, maximum likelihood can be applied to find the best $R_{true}$.

The technical issue is usually how to represent rotations, so that averaging will also yield a rotation. My favorite method is to consider the exponential representation $R = e^{[\bf{r}]_{\times }}$ where $\bf{r}$ is a vector and $[\bf{r}]_{\times}$  is the antisymmetric matrix that is equivalent to the cross product. Averaging the $\bf{r}$ over the measured rotations will give you a representation of an new rotation that is in some way an average of the original 10. In order to extract these vectors, given the original rotation matrices, please refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) wikipedia entry, which has more details on the exponential representation.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at that.